# NVIDIA GeForce GT 220 Noise

Tags: graphics-card, noise

I have an AMD Phenom II X4 945 / 3.0 GHz computer (HP Pavilion Elite HPE-130f)
The graphics card makes a lot of noise. Can I try to clean it? There may be a dust problem.

I already tried to blow away any dust on top of it, but it was of no use.

When I view youtube videos or stream to my TV, it makes a lot of noise. The GPU temp shows around 80 degrees. What can I do? Buy a new one?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For a 220, I'd start with a can of compressed air and use that to try and clean the dust out.

If that doesn't work, then generally the only other option is to replace the cooler - however that might not be worth it if you have to spend half the price of the card on a new fan. Up to you to decide if it's worth the hassle, or cheaper in time+money to just get a new card with a quieter fan and be done with it.